# How to identify if a PHAsset is not completely downloaded from iCloud (so I need to request again with options.networkAccessAllowed)

Tags: ios, photokit, phasset

The docs say:

> PHImageResultIsInCloudKey:
>   A Boolean value indicating whether the photo asset data is stored on the local device or must be downloaded from iCloud. (NSNumber)
>   If YES, no image was provided, because the asset data must be downloaded from iCloud. To download the data, submit another request, and specify YES for the networkAccessAllowed option.

But this key is always YES when a asset is stored in the iCloud Photo Library, even when it is already completely downloaded to the device (downloaded it in my app, also opened it in the Photos app).

If an image is not available I want to give the user a possibility to download it (but don't do it automatically, at least not when no Wifi is around).

So how do I find out if the image needs to be downloaded?

Even more curious: When my result block of
`requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:`
is called for an image that needs to be downloaded, I get a last call with requestedImage == nil, after a smaller and degraded version was delivered.

In this case degraded is NO, even that I got no image and the image still has to be downloaded from iCloud as only a small thumbnail from the Photos app is locally available so far.

I tested this on iPhones and iPads with different iOS 8 versions (8.1.x, 8.2 beta, 8.3 beta) the behavior is always the same.

Once I opened the image in the Photos app, the last call of the result handler has the full size image, but PHImageResultIsInCloudKey will still be YES.

Here's some code how I request the images:

```
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc]init];
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;
options.networkAccessAllowed = NO;

[self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:size contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage *requestedImage, NSDictionary *info) {
    // Checking for requestedImage and the info keys here
    // When a full sized image was loaded, the result of PHImageResultIsInCloudKey is still YES
    // When a full sized image couldn't be loaded cause it's in the cloud, isDegraded is NO and PHImageResultIsInCloudKey is YES (as always) and requestedImage is nil
}];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can confirm that PHImageResultIsInCloudKey is not reliable. For images stored in iCloud it returns 1, even though the original image has been downloaded to the device. This behavior is in contrast to the documentation and I would suggest to report a bug at radar.apple.com. PhotoKit in my opinion is still a very immature framework - it contains lots of issues and also some weird conceptional decisions.

Comment: Thanks for verifying this. So I will do some more testing if it seems to be safe to check for "requestedImage == nil" as a hint that the asset needs to be downloaded. The quoted docs above say "no image was provided, because the asset data must be downloaded from iCloud" so at least this part is correct. ;) Will also file a bugreport.

Comment: In my interpretation, the documentation is correct, and this behavior is also correct. It gives you all the data you need to do whatever is it you want to do: the UIImage, and the information. If you've got the image and it is not degraded, it doesn't matter to you if this image is in iCloud or not. It might be! And it's correct when it returns 1 because the image really is in iCloud, even though the API has finished downloading to you and gave it to you in this method.

Comment: The documentation says "If YES, no image was provided, because the asset data must be downloaded from iCloud.". So if it provides an image AND has 1 for the key, the documentation is wrong...

Answer (score 15):

If you call `requestImageDataForAsset:` with `networkAccessAllowed` set to `NO`, the returned `imageData` will be `nil` if the clip is not already downloaded from iCloud. Otherwise it will return the actual data, even though the clip is stored in iCloud.

```
PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];    
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.networkAccessAllowed = NO;
[manager
 requestImageDataForAsset:asset
 options:options
 resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
    if ([[info valueForKey:PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] boolValue]) {
    // Image is in iCloud
        if (imageData) {
            // Image is downloaded
        } else {
            // Image is not downloaded
        }
    }
 }];
```

Comment: I would suggest that we should check imageData on priority and if image data is nil then we should check is image in iCloud and download image from iCloud.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the progressHandler to check whether the PHAsset is from iCloud.

```
__block BOOL isPhotoInICloud = NO;
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.progressHandler = ^(double progress, NSError *error, BOOL *stop, NSDictionary *info){

    isPhotoInICloud = YES;
    // some code to update the download progress
});
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
options.synchronous = NO;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
// use the options to get the high quality image for only once time.
});
```

Comment: Another link may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966571/check-given-phasset-is-icloud-asset/40353694#40353694

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check if a PHAsset is still in the cloud is to try and access it through PHImageManager with networkAccessAllowed = NO, and if you don't get the image/asset, then you know it's still in the cloud (and it won't be downloaded):

```
    + (void)checkCloudStatusForPHAsset:(PHAsset*)phAsset completion:(void (^)(BOOL isInCloud))completionBlock
{
    if (phAsset) {
        if (phAsset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeVideo) {
            PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
            options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;
            options.deliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
            options.networkAccessAllowed = NO;
            [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:phAsset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                completionBlock(asset == nil);
            }];
        }
        else if (phAsset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeImage) {
            PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
            options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;
            options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
            options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeNone;
            options.networkAccessAllowed = NO;
            [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:phAsset options:options resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                completionBlock(imageData == nil);
            }];
        }
        else {
            completionBlock(NO);
        }
    }
    else {
        completionBlock(NO);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles across this while trying to resolve a bug in iOS 13.

The method in this thread has been DEPRECATED since iOS 8.

In iOS 13 you need to call this method instead:

```
- (PHImageRequestID)requestImageDataAndOrientationForAsset:(PHAsset *)asset 
                                                   options:(PHImageRequestOptions *)options 
                                             resultHandler:(void (^)(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, CGImagePropertyOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info))resultHandler;
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/3237282-requestimagedataandorientationfo