# PHImageManager requestImageDataForAsset behaves different on iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, photosframework

I'm using requestImageDataForAsset to detect if a video PHAsset is completely downloaded from iCloud.

I've **avoided** using the 'PHImageResultIsInCloudKey' from the requestImageDataForAsset resultHandler 'info' param, since it was/is not reliable( return 1 although the movie was already downloaded, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482275/how-to-identify-if-a-phasset-is-not-completely-downloaded-from-icloud-so-i-need)).

I've also detected that once the video PHAsset was on the device the 'PHImageFileURLKey' returns with a file url with a *.MOV suffix, via the 'info' param.

This worked for iOS8-9.2.1, but seems to be broken on iOS9.3b3 ,(didn't check the previous betas)

**Now** for any movie file which was captured on the device, PHImageFileURLKey is pointing to a file with '*.JPG' suffix (probably the movie thumb)

**Note:**
I've tried to use the other video api's:

1. requestPlayerItemForVideo
2. requestExportSessionForVideo
3. requestAVAssetForVideo

However they have a performance penalty which was not acceptable. 
requestImageDataForAsset is much faster.

Is that a bug that apple fixed in requestImageDataForAsset, which was not supposed to return PHImageFileURLKey to a movie, or a bug in iOS9.3b3 which now returns a path to an image(JPG)?