# How can I determine if the user has iCloud Photo Library turned on or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am accessing the user's photos for uploading from PHPhotoLibrary, but I need to be able to tell if they have iCloud Photo Library turned on or not.

If they have iCloud Photo Library, then they will have a photo album titled 'All Photos' - which they won't have if iCloud Photo Library is turned off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's any straight-forward way to do this. However, there are two workarounds that I am familiar with:

1. Check the `localizedTitle` of `assetCollection` with `subType` of `PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary`. The `localizedTitle` will be *"Camera Roll"* for iCloud disabled devices, and *"All Photos"* for iCloud enabled devices. **Keep in mind that if Apple changes the name in the future, it would break.**
2. Each `PHAsset` object has a `sourceType`. For iCloud photos, the value would be `PHAssetSourceTypeCloudShared`. The bad thing about this method is that if the user does not have photos on iCloud *at the moment*, you won't be able to say that it does have iCloud Photo Library disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the question, but a similar query would be determining whether each picture is in iCloud or on the device.  In which case [bcattle's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161906/bcattle) [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34937592/5342853) should do the trick: